# Use local lib instead of nexus one

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Using gradle to build Android project. Library com.test.x is fetched from nexus. During development, I want to overwrite the nexus lib with one, which I placed in the libs folder.

In gradle build file:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.test:com.test.x:version'
```

The error I'm getting:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.test.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/test/x/...;
```

Seems that there is a problem, because lib is now twice in project? How could this be resolved? Or is there another way to solve the matter?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `debugCompile` for the local copy and `releaseCompile` for the artifact, to tie the dependency to the build type.

For example, I do that in many of my CWAC libraries, though in my case it's a library module that my demo apps depend upon, not a JAR:

```
dependencies {
    debugCompile project(':provider')
    releaseCompile 'com.commonsware.cwac:provider:0.2.+'
}
```

Only one of those dependencies will be used for a build, based on the build type (`debug` or `release`).